# How to host a static webpage on Amazon Lightsail with a wordpress instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, server, bitnami

I have an instance of Wordpress on Amazon Lightsail, Wordpress is installed on a subdomain, I used the Bitnami image that Lightsail offers. I want to host a static page in the main domain, example: "https://www.expample.com". I have tried the solution that gives Bitnami, simply upload the files to the path: / opt / bitnami / apache2 / htdocs / I tried this but if I access with my browser to the main domain nothing appears

I want to solve this and upload a static website that points to this domain.

Comment: Think i must change something on the httpd-vhosts.conf file, but I don´t know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the directory `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/` since you're using a WordPress Stack and Apache is configured to serve the content of the directory `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/` at the root of your domain.

Please visit Bitnami Documentation for WordPress at AWS for more information:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress