# Static page with bitnami

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I'm running bitnami with WordPress on an AWS Lightsail instance, and I'd like to host some static content without destroying WordPress.

`/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` has the `VirtualHost` `DocumentRoot` set to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`, but adding a file like "demo.html" there doesn't work. It just reaches the WordPress "Page not found".

Is there an elegant way of doing this? Either a subfolder or subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put content into `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/`. The answer was already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252129/how-to-host-a-static-webpage-on-amazon-lightsail-with-a-wordpress-instance)